# Linux - copying files like on Windows (ignoring case with the same names)

Tags: linux, bash, copy

How can I copy files to ignore their case?
For example, I want to copy the test.txt file to the target directory, which already has Test.txt (same name, different case).
However, I don't want it to be copied as a new file, but to replace the existing one.

I want to get the same file copy effect as on Windows. Windows is case insensitive, so files and directories with the same name but different case are overwritten.
I would like to improve the installation of mods for games installed with Wine/Proton. I have to use Windows applications like 'Total Commander' to get everything copied properly.

Comment: You can use find's `-iname` option to search for a file with the same name regardless of case, and use that as the target.

Comment: One can write a custom function to take care of your use case. What should happen in case of mutlipe existence of the same file name in different case combination in the target folder?

Comment: You could use [ciopfs](https://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/)

Comment: `shopt -s nocaseglob; cp test.txt destination/test.txt*`

Comment: @oguzismail `nocaseglob` will not overwrite destination file regardless of case. You need a case insensitive filesystem or wrapper like ciops. Here is how it does not work with `nocaseglob`: `shopt -s nocaseglob; echo hello >BoB.txt echo ' world' >>bob.txt;  cat bob.txt; cat BoB.txt` Both file written rather than BoB.txt overwritten as op wants: *However, I don't want it to be copied as a new file, but to replace the existing one.*

Comment: @LéaGris I know, but that's not what OP asks.

Comment: @oguzismail, I copied the last sentence of the question and I read it as: He wants to overwrite any destination file whose name matches regardless of casing, instead of copying as a new file. For example: If source file is `BobyTables.sql`, and there is a file name `BOBYTABLES.SQL` at destination, he wants `BOBYTABLES.SQL` overwritten.

Comment: @LéaGris Read the rest of the question, there is nothing about redirections there. And as to your example, `shopt -s nocaseglob; cp BobyTables.sql destination/BobyTables.sql*` overwrites `destination/BOBYTABLES.SQL` if it exists (what would happen otherwise, and how it could be averted is out of the scope of a comment).